# Log the files found with the linux find and sed command

Tags: sed, find, logs, pattern-matching

I have a folder with txt, html, jpg and png files.
Now I want to go over all textbased files (txt and html) and start a search and replace.
I did the following and it is working fine:

```
find ./ -iregex '.*\.\(txt\|html\)$' -exec sed -i 's/search/replace/g' {} +
```

But now I also want to log the files in which a replacement was executed.
Let's say I have five txt and/or html files in my folder. But in only two of them there will be something replaces because the string `search` is in them.
So after the command I want to have a log file (for example `myLog.log`) in which the two files are printed (full path).

But how can I achieve such a command?
The [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command does not have such a parameter/option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to search fist for `search` pattern, then `sed`, and log.

try (line break for readability)

```
find ./ -iregex '.*\.\(txt\|html\)$' \
    -exec grep -q search {} \;  \
    -print \
    -exec sed -i 's/search/replace/g' {} + \
    > my-sed.log
```

where

- `search` in `-exec grep -q search {} \;` is your search pattern. Note that you can't use `+` who will match more that one file.
- `-print` print matched file, and thus can log

Comment: I would also probably change that messy `-iregex` thing into `\( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.html' \)` for clarity (and also to make it somewhat more portable).